# How the referencing of array elements work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

In low level languages like C/C++, arrays are "contiguous sequence of memory locations containing values of same type", as they contain values of same data type, elements can be accessed directly using the index (base address + index*(size of data type)). But in JavaScript, arrays can contain different data typed values so address calculation using index and base address is not possible. Can you please explain the backgrounds of accessing array elements in JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't run on a CPU, there is no memory. It defines its own memory model which the engine has to emulate, how it does that is up to the engine.

Comment: its similar to C, just use the index to randomly access the array in O(1) time

Comment: Bear in mind that what the JavaScript spec says and how a JS engine implements it are two entirely separate things.  I can well imagine that a modern JS engine could detect that an array will only ever contain numbers (for example), and when JITed is treated much like a c/c++ array.

Comment: JavaScript arrays and objects actually tend to behave a bit more like hash-maps than a C/C++ arrays. JavaScript doesn't support pointers or any sort of direct pointer arithmetic. Of course, the engine is free to implement it in any way it wants for performance reasons.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, Can you please explain how that index based accessing will work internally when arrays allow different data typed values.

Comment: @SudhirK You can read through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike C/C++, JavaScript is an interpreted language. That means that the language itself does not make any assumptions about the structure of memory used. Theoretically you could be a JavaScript interpreter, if you would take a paper and a pen and "execute" the code by hand. Therefore your question cannot be answered definetly: The engine can represent values in any way, as long as that behaves according to the specification.

The specification only says that:

1) Values in Javascript can have various types, Objects are a certain value type.

2) Objects are a group of key-value pairs, whereas keys are strings and values are any value

3) arrays are very special objects that also allow numbers as keys (and floors them to the nearest integer), and got a special `length` property.

---

Now if I would write a JS interpreter in C, I would first of all try to represent a "JavascriptValue" in some way, as some kind of union type:

```
union JavaScriptValue {
  Number;
  String;
  Boolean;
  Undefined;
  Object;
}
```

Now an object could be represented as

```
 unordered_map<JavaScriptValue, JavaScriptValue>
```